# PublishTestResults updating TFS Tests

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, automated-tests, azure-pipelines

We have a release pipeline which deploys our product, then runs some cucumber tests which produce junit output.  We then use PublishTestResults to publish this junit results.
This will then show the results in the Test Tab of the pipeline.

These tests are checked in to TFS source control but do not exist in the Test Tab of TFS.

We would like to create an empty TFS Test for each cucumber tests, and have the result of the test, updated after each pipeline is deployed, from the junit test report.  Is this possible with PublishTestResults or another method.

[image: release pipeline]

Answer (score 0):

It's not able to do this through publish test result test task.

> This task publishes test results to Azure Pipelines or TFS when tests
>   are executed to provide a comprehensive test reporting and analytics
>   experience. You can use the test runner of your choice that supports
>   the results format you require. Supported results formats include
>   CTest, **JUnit** (including PHPUnit), NUnit 2, NUnit 3, Visual Studio
>   Test (TRX), and xUnit 2.
>
> **The published test results are displayed in the Tests tab in the pipeline summary** and help you to measure pipeline quality, review
>   traceability, troubleshoot failures, and drive failure ownership.

You could also take a look at the concept of [TFS test case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/create-test-cases?view=azure-devops). Sorry not similar with cucumber tests, but after google, it looks like also not suit for build-in tfs test case.

So it's easy to publish the generated test result to tests tab in pipeline summary. But it's not possible to publish cucumber tests to TFS Test Manager with PublishTestResults or another method.